# making a list of random integers on prolog

Tags: list, prolog

So my problem is this i have this predicate which is n_aleatorios(El,INF,SUP,L) in which El is the lenght of the list, INF is the lower limit value of the list, SUP is the upper limit value of the list, and L is a list.

The objective of this predicate is to create a list of random integers.

The problem is that this is giving true as a result instead of unifying and giving the list as the result.

auxiliar predicates:

```
/*Checks if a number isnt a member of a list*/

nao_membro(_, []).

nao_membro(X, [P | R]) :- X \== P,
                          nao_membro(X, R).

/*Joins an integer in a sorted list, in a sorted order*/

insere_ordenado(El,[],[El]).

insere_ordenado(El,[P|R],[P|L2]) :- El >= P,
                                    insere_ordenado(El,R,L2).

insere_ordenado(El,[P|R],[El,P|R]) :- El < P.

/*Joins a random integer in a sorted list, in a sorted order*/

junta_novo_aleatorio(L1,INF,SUP,L2) :- random_between(INF, SUP, N),
                                       nao_membro(N,L1),
                                       insere_ordenado(N,L1,L2).
```

Program:

```
n_aleatorios(El,INF,SUP,L) :- n_aleatorios(El,INF,SUP,[],0).

n_aleatorios(El,_,_,L,El).

n_aleatorios(El,INF,SUP,L,AC) :- AC =< El,
                                 junta_novo_aleatorio(L,INF,SUP,L2),
                                 AC_num is AC +1,
                                 n_aleatorios(El,INF,SUP,L2,AC_num).
```

My output:

```
?- n_aleatorios(3, 1, 5, Lst).
true ;
false.
```

Expected output (for example):

```
?- n_aleatorios(3, 1, 5, Lst).
Lst = [2,3,5]
```

Really any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

One slight improvement here:

```
nao_membro(X, [P | R]) :- 
   X =\= P, 
   nao_membro(X, R).
```

Use "arithmetic non-equivalence" `=\=` instead of "structural non-equivalence" `\==` if we can be assured that neither `X` nor `P` are fresh. Indeed, here they are always integers.

Fixed code:

```
junta_novo_aleatorio(L1,INF,SUP,L2) :- 
   random_between(INF, SUP, N),
   nao_membro(N,L1),
   insere_ordenado(N,L1,L2).

n_aleatorios(Count,INF,SUP,L) :- 
   n_aleatorios(Count,INF,SUP,[],L).

n_aleatorios(Count,_,_,L,L) :- 
   length(L,Count),!.

n_aleatorios(Count,INF,SUP,Lin,Lout) :- 
   length(Lin,Len), Len<Count,!,
   junta_novo_aleatorio(Lin,INF,SUP,Lmid),
   n_aleatorios(Count,INF,SUP,Lmid,Lout).
```

Problems are due to the fact that the list to be constructed is not "threaded" properly between the predicates calls. Here, `Lin` is the "input list". It is where information "flows into" the predicate. `Lin` is is used to construct a new list `Lout`, which appears again the in the predicate argument, but now information "flows out" of the predicate back to the caller.

I have also eliminated the counter, which is already implicit in the length of `Lin`.

Note that selection between the two clauses of `n_aleatorios/5` occurs via a guard followed by a "cut" which commits to the execution path. The second "cut" is actually not needed, because there is no clause below, but makes things clear:

```
n_aleatorios(Count,_,_,L,L) :- 
   length(L,Count),!,...(we will never try any clause below)..

n_aleatorios(Count,INF,SUP,Lin,Lout) :- 
   length(Lin,Len), Len<Count,!,....(we will never try any clause below)..
```